# How do I list property names for an object using JMESPath?

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-cli, jmespath

I have a situation where the objects I am querying have unknown property names, and I would like to query the property **names** using JMESPath.

Here is an Azure CLI command and example output for it...Is there a way to get the names of the triggers without getting the value?

```
az logic workflow list --query "[].{name:name, triggers:definition.triggers}"
```

```
[
  {
    "name": "MyFirstLogicApp",
    "triggers": {
      "When_I_upload_a_new_video": {
        ...bunch of json...
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "MySecondLogicApp",
    "triggers": {
      "When_an_S3_object_is_updated": {
        ...bunch of json...
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "MyThirdLogicApp",
    "triggers": {
      "When_a_file_is_created_(properties_only)_(V2)": {
        ...bunch of json...
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "MyFourthLogicApp",
    "triggers": {
      "When_a_file_is_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)": {
        ...bunch of json...
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Sorry but is there any other way you can ask your question or at least clarify the requirement? Personally, I’m a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [keys function](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#keys) to get only the keys of the provided object:

```
az logic workflow list --query "[].{name:name, triggers:keys(definition.triggers)}"
```

Comment: There is no attribute *definition*. Remove it from the query `"[].{name:name, triggers:keys(triggers)}"`